# How to know the element according to the class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this:

```
$(".myclass").on("click", function(){
    // I need to know what's the clicked element? i.e. div, a, span, etc ..
})
```

As I've commented in code above, I need to get the tag name of the clicked element. Is it possible to know that?

Comment: `console.log($(this));`

Comment: `this` is your friend

Comment: @tymeJV `that` won't do.

Comment: @Samuel - why not? Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/hg639opy/1/

Comment: @tymeJV I'm just playing

Comment: Ohhhh - wow, I just saw `that` in the code tildes... ayyyy <3

Comment: Just add `alert(this.className);` in your posted click handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for the string name of the element use [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

```js
$(".myclass").on("click", function() {
  console.clear()
  // Vanilla JS
  console.log('Vanilla: ' + this.tagName)
  // jQuery
  console.log('jQuery: ' + $(this).prop("tagName"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="myclass">Click Me!</h1>
<div class="myclass">NO! Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: Well I don't see `div` in the console.

Comment: It prints out `DIV` for me in upper case

Comment: And a fiddle in case you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/hg639opy/1/

Comment: It prints nothing for me  ... anyone else gets `DIV` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ - Are you looking in the console?

Comment: `console.log('Vanilla: ' + this.tagName)` and you can drop `e.target`

Comment: huh... I have never done that before, I like that :)